# Printing from web browser causes content to be cut off at the top and bottom of pages

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 grid layout (row, col-md4, etc.). When I go to print a page, the content is being cut off at the top and bottom of each page, like so:

[image]

What causes this? Do I need to add some kind of special markup to prevent this from happening?